# Submit Checked Status of Recyclerview Items In JSON Object Android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, hashmap

I have a list of items in recyclerview which has a checkbox for each row. I have successfully gotten the checked items and their values from adapter and send them to activity using a hashmap like below:

```
private HashMap<String, String> attendanceMap;

viewholder.attendanceCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b){
                playerSession.setPresent(b);
                attendanceMap.put(itemsList.get(position).getUserId_player(), "1");
                sendToActivity();
            }
        }
    });

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> viewer : attendanceMap.entrySet()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Players in map:\t" + viewer.getKey() + " \t and status in map:\t" + viewer.getValue());
    }

public HashMap<String, String> sendToActivity() {
    return attendanceMap;
}
```

and in activity I have gotten the values like below:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = adapter.sendToActivity();
```

I want to submit the `player_id and att_status` gotten from adapter in the activity by using json object in my post method. I have tried retrieving all the values by looping through them and adding them to json object like below:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("prg_user_map_id", progUserMapId);
        jsonObject.put("prg_session_id", progSessId);
        jsonObject.put("batch_id", batchId);
        jsonObject.put("coach_id", coachId);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> viewer : map.entrySet()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Players in map:\t" + viewer.getKey() + " \t and status in map:\t" + viewer.getValue());
        try {
            jsonObject.put("player_id", viewer.getKey());
            jsonObject.put("att_status", viewer.getValue());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Att_Status in obj:\t" + jsonObject.get("att_status") +
                "\tPlayer id in object:\t" + jsonObject.get("player_id"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but the log only prints one item and subsequently my network request only posts one item from player_id and att_status. Am I looping through the object items incorrectly? Can someone help out with this? Thanks.

Comment: yes you are looping them incorrectly , in loop values are getting overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop like below

```
    StringBuilder keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> viewer : map.entrySet()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Players in map:\t" + viewer.getKey() + " \t and status in map:\t" + viewer.getValue());
        keyBuilder.append(viewer.getKey()).append("\n");
        valueBuilder.append(viewer.getValue()).append("\n");
    }
    try {
        jsonObject.put("player_id", keyBuilder.toString());
        jsonObject.put("att_status", valueBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Great !! Thank you !